# Facebook API 3.6.0 login fails with FB app installed on phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am building an app, which is going to have support for facebook.I have downloaded facebook API 3.6.0
The problem is with login - if original FB app is not installed on phone, the login is going through custom dialog 
and everything works Fine,but if FB app is installed, the login is going through custom dialog and automatically redirect to original FB app,
 and then nothing happened.I have tested this on different phones, and always was the same problem.

I used this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) to generate the hashkey.
In my facebook-sdk 3.6.0 I can't find this: 
`private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false` to `true`.

Anyone can help?  login activity code here :

```
    public class Login extends Activity {
SessionManager session;
EditText etLoginusername;
EditText etLoginPass;
String cus_email, cus_pass, cus_id, cus_mob, cus_name, cus_points, success,
        fb_id, id;
Button btnLogin, btnForgotPass, btnfblogin;
ToggleButton remToggle;
int REM_STATUS;
public static Facebook fb;
SharedPreferences sp;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btnfblogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bfb);
    btnfblogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // fb login code start
            String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
            fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            if (access_token != null) {
                fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if (expires != 0) {
                fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            // code for generated facebook hash key
            try {
                PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.amar.facebookexample",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    System.out.println("KeyHash : "
                            + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                                    Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }

            if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
                // button logout
                try {
                    fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                    fblogin();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
            // button Login
            fb.authorize(Login.this, new String[] { "email" },
                    new DialogListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "fbError",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "OnError",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Editor editor = sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    fb.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    fb.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                            session.save(fb, Login.this);
                            fblogin();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Oncancel",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            }

        }
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fblogin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
            obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
            id = obj.optString("id");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fb_id", id));
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = LoginHttpClient
                    .executeHttpPost(
                            "http://10.0.2.2/Upshot_Loyalty_Program/android_api/get_fb_id.php",
                            postParameters);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                success = json_data.getString("success");
                cus_id = json_data.getString("cus_id");
                cus_name = json_data.getString("cus_name");
                cus_points = json_data.getString("cus_points");
                // User_List.add(json_data.getString("cus_id"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (success.equals("1")) {
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            session.createLoginSessionRemMe(cus_id, cus_name, cus_points);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Userpage1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mobileno.class);
            i.putExtra("fb_id", id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your login code?

Comment: @JonAnderPeñalba i have posted my login code, plz check it.

Answer (score 0):

This should temporarily solve it

```
fb.authorize(Login.this, new String[] { "email" },Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,              new DialogListener()
```